# friendly URL remap format in DNN

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke, friendly-url

we have a custom module on our DNN site that creates unique URLs for each entry from an underlying database.  The URLs would look something like this:

```
something/afn/something_else
```

A snippet from a full URL:

```
tabid/66/afn/160529-David%20Lewis-000258-010-003-00001
```

Without a trailing /Default.aspx.  The module would see the /afn/, process the something_else, and if valid, render the unique page accordingly.

We just upgraded to DNN 8.0.3, and this is no longer working, instead we are getting 404 errors from IIS.  We discovered if we append /Default.aspx to the URL, it works as it's supposed to.  Changing the module to put /Default.aspx when the page is generated is simple.  However that leaves countless links on our page, and on the web, that no longer work.

After much research I found the Friendly URL Settings in DNN under Host -> Host Settings -> Advanced Settings.  This appears to have a way to remap URLs.  The trouble I'm having is formatting the remap correctly.

My question:

What can I enter in the Friendly URL Settings so that if a user clicks on a url formatted like this:

```
ourwebsite.org/something/afn/something_else
```

it changes it to:

```
ourwebsite.org/something/afn/something_else/Default.aspx
```

Thank you very much.

EDITED: to add real life example URL.

Answer (score 0):

WIth current DNN this should not be the case as the Default.aspx at the end isn't needed.  In your upgrade, depending on the prior version, you will want to validate the "Url Settings" for the portal to ensure that for some reason that you don't have extensions turned on.  Otherwise, when you upgraded did you see any errors?  What version did you upgrade from.

Based on the standard setup of DNN URL's, this should work as desired assuming that /something/afn is the URL to a particular page.  Or that something is the page and afn is the querystring.

Example /something?afn=something_else

Whereby you are expecting to see a Request.QueryString["afn"] value for the something_else value.

Comment: This leads me to believe it's an IIS configuration issue.  I've seen multiple reference to adding a default handler mapping to IIS (*), and have tried them.  So far nothing has worked, so maybe I'm doing it wrong?  This is IIS on Server 2012 R2.